# matlab coder.extrinsic, define / initialize more complex data type

Tags: matlab, simulink

Working with matlab system blocks in Simulink and coder.extrinsic. In [this link](https://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/use-matlab-engine-to-execute-a-function-call-in-generated-code.html), under the "Working with mxArrays" heading, it says y has to be defined as a scalar double in order for the code to work, since the function will return a scalar double.

But what about more complex data types, such as a python module? To clarify:

```
% foo(x) returns a double scalar

coder.extrinsic('foo', 'py.importlib.import_module');
y = 0; % define y as double scalar
y = foo(x); % works fine

np =  ??? ; % how do I define np so that the row below will work? 
np = py.importlib.import_module('numpy');
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice here is to put everything under a matlab (example.m) function under the same working directory, put all the python calls and variables inside it and call that matlab function from the Simulink function block. This way you won't run into those horrible define errors:

```
%--- example.m file (exists in the working directory)
function y = example(x)
  y = foo(x);  
  d = py.np.array() 
  %all python functions go here
end

% ---- inside the Simulink Matlab Function Block
coder.extrinsic('example');
out = 0; %preallocate the output
out = example()
```